# How to reverse proxy activeadmin application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, activeadmin

I'd like the 2 parts of my rails / activeadmin application to be accessed directly from 2 differents subdomain:

```
admin.domain.tld => http://localhost:9999/admin/login
api.domain.tlp => http://localhost:9999
```

I came up with this configuration but this is not working:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name admin.domain.tld;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9999/admin;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Note: in ActiveAdmin, /admin automatically redirect to /admin/login

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.domain.tld;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9999;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to set this up ?

Comment: Is the admin.app_domain.ltd redirected to your app?

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean ?

Comment: If you created a subdomain admin.domain.ltd in your DNS provider and pointed it to your server?

Comment: yes, this part is fine ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you redirect the subdomain to your app, i think a good way to resolve that is check the request subdomain and if it's equal to admin, then redirect to /admin. You can do that in application controller on the default action 
EX:

```
if request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain == 'admin' 
  redirect_to admin_path
end
```

In the admin_path i mean the path for the default route of activeadmin...
I never worked with that gem...

I think you can deal with the subdomains in your app, you just need to redirect them to the app and in the first controller you check for where you want to redirect.. But this is just one way to deal with that. Of course there is someway to do that by the virtual hosts configuration...

If you don't want to do this in your application_controller.rb you can do on the first controller responsible by the root of your application. Imagine you have:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_subdomains, :only=>[:index]

  def index 

  end

  private

  def check_subdomains
    if request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain == 'admin' 
      redirect_to admin_path
    elsif  request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain == 'api'
      redirect_to api_path
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Usually, I do not modify application controller, what is the best way to deal with it ? What is the default action you would use ?